# issues with title and description of my website in Bing results

Tags: seo, bing

I have problems with title and description tags
The site link appears incorrectly in **Bing** only!
[image]
I searched a lot without finding a solution
Please help

Comment: We don't really do individual SEO reviews here, so you'll need to supply what the issues are with the title and description specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Microsoft is very picky. 
If you check out the link below it will tell you how Bing handles the search results. 
Typically you can change this via page description in your header.

```
Under the description tag in your meta.
```

Hope this helps. [Click for more information.](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/webmaster-guidelines-30fba23a)